# How to refactor following class

Tags: c++, class, refactoring, dry

I am developing key-value database (https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4)

There I have code like this:

```
enum class Command{
    INFO    ,
    SAVE    ,
    RELOAD  ,

    GET ,
    GETX    ,

    COUNT   ,
    SUM ,
    MIN ,
    MAX 
};

template<class PROTOCOL, class DB_ADAPTER, class CONNECTION>
class KeyValueWorkerProcessor{
    PROTOCOL    &protocol_;
    DB_ADAPTER  &db_;
    CONNECTION  &buffer_;

public:
    KeyValueWorkerProcessor(PROTOCOL &protocol, DB_ADAPTER &db, CONNECTION &buffer) :
                    protocol_(protocol),
                    db_(db),
                    buffer_(buffer){}

    auto operator()(Command cmd){
        switch(cmd){

        case Command::INFO  : return do_info();
        case Command::SAVE  : return do_save();
        case Command::RELOAD    : return do_reload();

        case Command::GET   : return do_get();
        case Command::GETX  : return do_getx();

        case Command::COUNT : return do_count();
        case Command::SUM   : return do_sum();
        case Command::MIN   : return do_min();
        case Command::MAX   : return do_max();

        default         : return err_NotImplemented_();
        }
    }

    // I have lots of these:

    WorkerStatus do_info();
    WorkerStatus do_save();
    WorkerStatus do_reload();

    WorkerStatus do_get();
    WorkerStatus do_getx();

    WorkerStatus do_count();
    WorkerStatus do_sum();
    WorkerStatus do_min();
    WorkerStatus do_max();
};

template<class PROTOCOL, class DB_ADAPTER, class CONNECTION>
auto do_something(PROTOCOL &protocol, DB_ADAPTER &db, CONNECTION &buffer, Command cmd){
    using MyKeyValueWorkerProcessor = KeyValueWorkerProcessor<PROTOCOL, DB_ADAPTER, CONNECTION>;

    MyKeyValueWorkerProcessor processor{ protocol, db, buffer };

    return processor(cmd);
};
```

To avoid creating lots of functions with same parameters - `PROTOCOL`, `DB_ADAPTER` and `CONNECTION`, I create templated `class KeyValueWorkerProcessor`.

This save lots of boilerplate code e.g. else I need to do:

```
template<class PROTOCOL, class DB_ADAPTER, class CONNECTION>
WorkerStatus do_info(PROTOCOL &protocol, DB_ADAPTER &db, CONNECTION &buffer);

template<class PROTOCOL, class DB_ADAPTER, class CONNECTION>
WorkerStatus do_save(PROTOCOL &protocol, DB_ADAPTER &db, CONNECTION &buffer);
```

etc.

However now, I have lots of methods in my templated `class KeyValueWorkerProcessor` and I definitely do not like that.

Any good way I can refactor this?

I am using C++17.

Comment: Are you using `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` for this somewhere?

Comment: no, skiplist(s) in memory and lots of files on the disk. read only version is just files on the disk, but you need somehow to create the disk files

Comment: OFF TOPIC: Do you think I should write on github that my database does not use `std::map`? Because at least on stackoverflow, lots of people asking me exactly this.

Comment: I don't think that's needed.  I looked at the presentation you had there and it seems you've considered using the standard `std::unordered_map` but that it wasn't good for some reason. Should be enough.